# jQuery give images without an alt-tag a border

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to give images without an alt-tag a border, I tried this but I'm very green so it's probably total crap

```
$( ':image:not([alt])' ).css('border', '5px solid red');
```

Comment: `$('img:not([alt])').css('border', '5px solid red');` Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3V3EZ/

Answer (score 1):

There's no `:image` selector in jQuery, you need to use:

```
$('img:not([alt])').css('border', '5px solid red');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

First, using :image is incorrect. You have to use

```
$("image")
```

to select the images.

An alternative is to use

```
[type="image"]
```

for readability. You can read more here: http://api.jquery.com/image-selector/

Then using

```
:not()
```

allows you to specify selectors. You can also use the .not(), and separate the selectors using commas or spaces. Refernce: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Therefore, to appropriate way to select all images on the page without the alt attribute, would be something like:

```
$("image:not(alt)").css('border', '5px solid red');
```

Hope this helps.